# Batch output to file contains Chinese symbols

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, wmic

since yesterday I try to create a batch file which writes several informations about the computer into a txt file which will later be used to keep a Database updates. The only problem is, that sometimes the output just ends up in random chinese symbols.

Here is an example of the current version of the batch files output.

```
SerialNumber 
XXXXXX
Manufacturer
FUJITSU // American Megatrends Inc.
Name
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz
```

Looks good so far but as soon as I want to add some text on my own or some bigger bits of information or normal text in between into the text file it writes it down in those damn symbols. Here is the output with "CPU" written between the Manufacturer and CPU information.

```
SerialNumber 
XXXXXX
Manufacturer
FUJITSU // American Megatrends Inc.
偃⁕਍Name
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz
```

The only problem is I have already tried to solve this problem with chcp 65001 and it still won't work properly. :/

Well here is the current code I'm using to write the informations into a txt file.

```
@SET PathSave=C:\Test.txt
@ECHO.
@ECHO Collecting Informations
@ECHO.
@ECHO Seriennummer
@wmic bios get serialnumber >> %PathSave%
@ECHO Marke
@wmic bios get manufacturer >> %PathSave%
@ECHO CPU
@wmic cpu get name >> %PathSave%
@ECHO Netzwerkadapter
@wmic nicconfig >> %PathSave%
@ECHO Press any key to complete!
@PAUSE > NUL
```

Maybe someone knows this cause already since I've seen some others trying to solve the problem, but everything I've tried so far didn't work.

Comment: `WMIC` outputs to UTF-16, this shouldn't be an issue if you read the output with something that reads that type of encoding natively.

Comment: I'm using notepad to open the .txt file and well.

Comment: That's your issue, notepad is not designed for files of that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple enough fix for times when you intend to read the UTF-16 LE (BOM) in a reader not compatible with that format.

Pipe the result through `More`, e.g.

```bat
@WMIC CPU Get Name|MORE>>"%PathSave%"
```

…and:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "PathSave=C:\Test.txt"
ECHO(
ECHO Collecting BIOS, CPU and Network Information
ECHO(

(   WMIC BIOS Get Manufacturer,SerialNumber
    WMIC CPU Get Name
    WMIC NICConfig)|MORE>"%PathSave%"

ECHO Press any key to complete ...
PAUSE>NUL
```

Comment: Thx this will help me to finish the tool off. By the way do you know a way to make something like this.
Var1 = Wmic Computername
Var2 = C:\<Var1>.txt
I just want to save the files names by the computers I've checked, if that was possible.

Comment: Each computers name is already in an environment variable, `%COMPUTERNAME%`, so you may be able to incorporate that into your output file name or path.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I've shrinked my batch now by arround 1-200 Characters which should be much better. Also thank you for the `wmic bios get <Info1>, <Info2>` which also cut off some unnecesary commands etc.
Now the only problem is, that I don't know how to save the file to one of our network folders, but I think it's just a little trick with _\\fileserver\>folder with public rights>_
Do I maybe need to give the folder like everyone and read and write rights to a folder so I could save it to that particular location